# Can the distributive lattice theorem be improved?

Tags: order-theory

The theorem I am referring to is the following: A lattice $L$ is distributive iff none of its sublattices is isomorphic to $M_3$ or $N_5$. Can this theorem be improved? More precisely, is there a single lattice $X$ such that a lattice $L$ is distributive iff none of its sublattices is isomorphic to $X$?

Comment: Hint: If $X$ is such a lattice, then $X$ is not distributive, and $M_3$ has a sublattice isomorphic to $X$, and $N_5$ has a sublattice isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: Note however that "has a copy of $N_5$" is equivalent to non-modularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as $M_3$ does not contain $N_5$ or vice versa, we need both in such a theorem.

Note the simularity to the planarity of graphs theorem by [Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski%27s_and_Wagner%27s_theorems) where we also have two "forbidden sub-objects" to characterise planarity. There a similar reasoning applies why we need two.